# Concatenate env variables in helm deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Say I want the following secrets to be used in a db connection string inside a helm template:

```
- name: DBUSER
  valueFrom:
   secretKeyRef:
     name: dbadmin
     key: username
- name: DBPASS
   valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: dbadmin
      key: password
```

Later I want to create this:

```
- name: Database__ConnectionString
  value: "server=something.com;port=3306;user=$DBUSER;password=$DBPASS;database=dbname"
```

How do I access the env values of DBUSER and DBNAME inside of that connection string value?

Answer (score 3):

Many places in a pod spec support `$(VARIABLE_NAME)` syntax.  In particular, the [API documentation for an `EnvVar` object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#envvar-v1-core) specifies

> `value` (*string*): Variable references $(VAR_NAME) are expanded using the previous defined environment variables in the container and any service environment variables.

so you should be able to say something like

```
- name: Database__ConnectionString
  value: "server=something.com;port=3306;user=$(DBUSER);password=$(DBPASS);database=dbname"
```

(Note the parentheses around `$(DBUSER)` and `$(DBPASS)`.)

(In this specific case some database libraries will let you specify all of the individual parts of a connection string as separate environment variables, so instead of doing this you might be able to set environment variables [`PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-envars.html) if you're using PostgreSQL for example.)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to handle this in your container, usually via a command wrapper like

```
command:
- bash
- -c
- export Database_ConnectionString=server=...;user=$DBUSER && exec mycommand
```

Or something like that